# Confused about groups and adduser

Tags: users, adduser

I have written a script to add chrooted sFTP users.

The useradd command is:

```
sudo useradd -Ng sftponly -ms /bin/false "$USER"
```

Did it work?

```
groups $USER
$USER : sftponly
```

Yes it did. Great!

Then I take a look at /etc/group and there is no $USER in sftponly. I try logging in and out (shouldn't need to - I am not $USER) and nothing changes. (for $USER == yoko):

```
ftp:x:114:
sftponly:x:1003:george,john,paul,ringo
incron:x:115:
```

Why am I seeing $USER in the correct group when using groups, but not in /etc/group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shall not use `useradd`, but use `adduser` instead. However, if you insist on using `useradd`, here is what you should do:

```
sudo useradd -Ng sftponly -G sftponly -ms /bin/false "$USER"
```

The `-g` option only changes the `/etc/passwd` file, making "sftponly" the primary (login) group ID of the user. The -G option modifies `/etc/groups`.

Comment: Isn't this redundant? I mean, is the user not also treated as member of the login-group set in /etc/passwd, even if he isn't listed in /etc/groups?

Comment: To be frank, good question. I'm not sure, i.e. I'm not sure whether there isn't any program that consults only `/etc/group` but not `/etc/passwd`. I think I will ask that on superuser.

Comment: Yeah - I understand now why they don't appear in `/etc/groups` but surely having all the information in one canonical spot makes more sense?

Answer (score 2):

From the `useradd` [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/useradd.8.html):

```
-g, --gid GROUP
    The group name or number of the user's initial login group.
```

The user's initial login group is the one at the fourth field in a line of the `/etc/passwd` file. If you look for "yoko" in `/etc/passwd` you'll find something like:

```
yoko:x:<yoko's UID>:1003::<yoko's home>:/bin/false
```

where `1003` is the GID of `sftponly` group.